# Connection string changes not picked up by ConfigurationManager

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, configurationmanager

I'm having a issue with `ConfigurationManager` not picking up a change to a connection string.

I'm sure there's a simple explanation, however I've been staring at it for the last two hours and given myself contextual blindness.

Inside a WCF project I've updated the database name of a named connection string in the `web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="appDb"
       connectionString="Data Source=HOST;Database=DB_NEW;User=X;Password=X;" 
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

There's a separate repository project that orchestrates the database connection, abstracting it from the WCF project. In that project it uses the connection string value from the web.config file, accessed using the following expression:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["appDb"].ConnectionString
```

*(The WCF project manages dependency injection using Unity and is responsible for creating an instance of the session factory in the referenced project for NHibernate's `ISessionFactory`.)*

However, at runtime it's still picking up the connection string prior to me changing it.

Things I've tried:

- *Full clean/rebuild of the entire solution*
- *iisreset*
- *Checked IIS physical path is the correct directory (I have multiple branches of the same project)*
- *Checked the connection string isn't being defined anywhere else in the solution*
- *Restarted Visual Studio (2015)*
- *No transforms being applied to the web.config*

The connection string value **must** be being cached somewhere, but where I do not know.

**Update**

Could this be NHibernate caching the connection string? Apologies I have very little knowledge with NHibernate (I'm usually EF).

```
var config = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration()
            .SetProperty(Environment.ConnectionString,
                ConfigurationManager
                    .ConnectionStrings["AppDb"].ConnectionString)
```

**Update**

IIS seems to recognise the new config in IIS Manager, so this confirms that it's being read from the file correctly.

[image]

Comment: if you remove this `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" ` and add `using  System.Data.SqlClient` to the class header and add the reference, does this work.. in this line.. can you show what variable you are assigning the following `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["appDb"].ConnectionString`

Comment: @MethodMan - which class header should I try adding the `using` to?

Comment: the class where you are using the connection to the database..

Comment: Could the connection string be overridden in a config transform? Maybe it's not getting the connection string you think it's getting.

Comment: @MethodMan - I tried your suggestion but I'm getting the same behaviour. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @ScottHannen - There are no transforms being applied to the config, I've double checked this.

Comment: How do you determine the problem, and what is the problem _exactly_? Are _you_ looking at the right database, if you're looking at it through for example SSMS?

Comment: Are there multiple projects involved?  Is the config setting in the config file of a related assembly?  Though each project in your solution can have its own config file, the only one that counts is the the executable's.

Comment: Since it sounds like you're running this locally, go into the bin/debug folder and look at the web.config there, and see if it has the connection string you expect.

Comment: @CodeCaster I have two identical databases on the same server, the only difference is the volume of data. I've put a breakpoint on the `ConfigurationManager` line and when it's hit it shows the value of the old config.

Comment: @STLDeveloper Yes, there are multiple projects, the config file I'm editing is in the parent WCF project. It's also the only config file to list any connection strings.

Comment: @ScottHannen I've checked the `*.dll.config` file for the WCF project in the bin directory and it contains the new correct value. This is driving me nuts.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by _"The connection is initialized in a referenced project using the following expression `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["appDb"].ConnectionString`"_?

Comment: @CodeCaster There's a separate repository project that orchestrates the database connection, abstracting it from the WCF project. In that project it uses the connection string value from the `web.config` file, accessed using the `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` collection.

Comment: Where is the repository project hosted and how do you communicate with it? Is it simply a referenced Dll?

Comment: @spodger Yes it's another project in the solution, referenced by the WCF project.